# Weird issue with iptables redirection

Tags: iptables, routing

I am trying to redirect all incoming traffic on UDP port 5060 to port 56790, and all outgoing traffic from 5060 to the port 56789. I used these iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp ! -s localhost --dport 5060 -j REDIRECT --to-port 56790
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p udp ! -s localhost --sport 5060 -j REDIRECT --to-port 56789
```

I listen on both ports using RAW SOCKETS after setting the interface to PROMISCUOUS mode using ioctl.

I see packets ONLY on 56789 i.e.SENDING side, and I do not see any packets on 56790, while wireshark shows that many packets are delivered to port 5060.

Why would this happen? Any ideas? Do you think it's a problem with iptables rules or something to do with raw sockets?

[This is ubuntu 10.04 and iptables v1.4.4]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question: (1) wireshark will look at packets as they come from the wire, so iptables rules for incoming packets do not apply; (2) your iptables rules apply to UDP, but you state that you open a raw socket.  Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve and what does not work as expected?

Comment: i am trying to build a transparent proxy for all traffic going in and coming out of port 5060. For that, I added the two iptables rules - one for redirecting incoming traffic, and another for redirecting output traffic. I see that only the outgoing packets are correctly redirected, and the packets for the input chain are NOT getting redirected to the intended port i.e. 56790. I can say so because I am running a simple application (tried both SOCK_RAW and SOCK_DGRAM) listening on port 56790, and it is not receiving any packet. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: May I see the output of `iptables-save`? You can obfuscate any public IP address in it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to transparently redirect packets arriving to port 5060/udp
to port 56790/udp, then you need two iptables rules for that: one for
incoming packets, and one to map reply packets (which have source port 56790)
back to remote destination port 5060:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j DNAT --to-destination :56790
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --sport 56790 -j SNAT --to-source :5060
```

Conversely, to redirect outgoing packets (originating from port 5060 and intended for port 5060) to port 56789, you swap the port numbers:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 57689 -j DNAT --to-destination :5060
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --sport 5060 -j SNAT --to-source :56789
```

Comment: And similarly for redirecting all output packets from 5060 through 56789 as :                                                              iptables -A POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j DNAT --to-destination :56789                                                                  Am I right? I will verify your incoming rules and let you know if they work. Thanks.

Comment: @skypemesm You just need to swap the port numbers; I've updated the answer text with the outgoing rules.

Comment: sudo iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip to:127.0.0.1:56790 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:56790 to::5060 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
 I have netcat listen on udp port 56790 while i run a sip application.

Comment: while i see packets coming into my ip adress:5060, I dont receive any packets on 56790. It is the same problem with these rules as well :(

Comment: @skypesm Weird... I tested the rules with netcat and they worked for me...

Comment: I tested this with netcat as well. It still appears on the netcat instance listening on port 5060, instead of 56790. Its very weird, and the even weirder thing is that this is happening on two of my machines - my laptop and my desktop. Instead of using iptables to perform such transparent udp proxying, can you suggest any other technique or library?

Comment: @skypesm Just to be sure that we ran the same tests: the rules above won't work when connecting for connections from one host to itself.  Have you tested connectiions between two different PCs?